# GloVe embeddings - unknown / out-of-vocabulary token

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, nlp, word-embedding, glove

I would like to know if there is a general (default) *out-of-vocabulary (OOV)* token for *GloVe* embeddings. In particular for the pre-trained ones from Stanford:
https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/

I found this on SO: [What is "unk" in glove.6B.50d.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239941/what-is-unk-in-glove-6b-50d-txt)

The given answer suggests that the token `"unk"` represents the *OOV-Token* and [shared a link to the Glove project on Github](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/GloVe/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=unk&type=) as evidence. 
However this doesn't seem very conclusive to me as the link only refers to `"<unk>"` tokens in the code (not `"unk"`), but `"<unk>"` does existent in the vocabulary!

So I would like to know, if there is any (default) *OOV-token* for GloVe (what can be used for unknown/unseen words) and if so what is it?

Comment: @jayelm Thank you for the answer and the notification!